# How to use Delicious 2.3.4 Firefox plugin on Linux?

Tags: firefox, delicious, linux

I have been happily using Delicious with Firefox for years but in the last time the plugin where I just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get a native window to add a bookmark and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to browse my bookmarks doesn't work anymore. I tried the Delicious service but it is much worse then the plugin (slow, no hotkeys, strange messages I don't care about like "this bookmark has already been saved by User X).

Now I won't ask why their innovation is going backwards as this is not the right place here and I guess it has to do with anything but user satisfaction (more like increase revenue by increasing time-on-site, exposure to advertisment and the like).

I would however just be happy to use my dead simple but fast and efficient plugin the way it used to. However when I look for a new version there are many different Delicious plugins. Can I somehow use any of them or is there some kind of fix to get the old one back to work?

P.S.: I noticed that on my Windows 8.1 machine the plugin still works. At my laptop with arch linux however I don't even find the right plugin with the addon search. Does this have something to do with the architecture or is the addon just not available anymore and I should copy it somehow from one machine to the other?

P.P.S.: The plugin is called "Delicious Bookmarks 2.3.4". It is not on the Firefox Addon list anymore but I located the xpi file. It still doesn't work on my Linux machine (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> does, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> gives me a HTML window that doesn't do what I want and says "... shutdown in April").

**Specs of my Linux machine:**

```
Firefox 28.0
3.14.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT
GNOME Shell 3.12.1
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but ..
I, myself, have finally had it with there being no replacement for the "really delicious" addon from the old days you speak of.  Not only has the old addon that I have kept running finally gone to a state of too many bugs, after days of searching I didn't find anything close to what was offered by it before (on any browser!).
So, I think it's gonna fail sooner or later if you even find a solution for that specific addon.

**So I decided to take it upon myself to create something similar.**
[Here is my new project about it.](http://attic.e-motiv.net/ff-delicious)
Currently only a toolbar tags-dropdown though, very soon a migration guide and later a sidebar.

I hope you are one of the fellows who remember the "good times" and I am not too late with all this. I fear most people might have given up earlier.

Comment: Great project! I wanted to do such a project myself but as a Java programmer I'm not experienced enough in the Firefox Plugin and Javascript department. Still, if there is something I can do to help I would be glad to participate if you need it!

Comment: Thx. And let me not mention the learning curve of firefox SDK!  Louzy docs and unfinished SDK ... Urgh! But well, I made it.
I am currently discussing with firefox devs what could be a DB migration problem. It might be a firefox bug or not.  So, if you would want to do my DB migration and let us know if you have the same results or not, you would certainly help me (or firefox developers giving us better bookmark tags results) Anyway, this will explain it better: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1172828
I could also release my addon code on GIT if you would like to join that too.